# Can only write with sudo to one USB flash memory

Tags: usb, flash

I suddenly can not write to one of my USB flash drives. I must do "gksu nautilus" to write to it. (When I give that command nautilus opens in my home folder but only shows desktop and download folders. If I go via /, all files in my home folder show. - Nautilus still opens OK if I do not use gksu.)

Can I get things back to normal?

Thanks

```
ycc@x360:/media/ycc$ pwd
/media/ycc
ycc@x360:/media/ycc$ ls -l
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 8 ycc ycc 32768 Aug  8 18:07 KINGSTON
ycc@x360:/media/ycc$ ls -l KINGSTON
total 1767520
drwxr-xr-x  3 ycc ycc      32768 Jun 18  2015 LP pdf
drwxr-xr-x  6 ycc ycc      32768 Aug  6 17:35 mbdyn_matlab_ycc
drwxr-xr-x  4 ycc ycc      32768 Jul  9 17:07 xxxxx bu
drwxr-xr-x  6 ycc ycc      32768 Jun 10 03:00 ycc_doc folders
drwxr-xr-x 13 ycc ycc      32768 Jun 10 03:00 ycc_images
-rw-r--r--  1 ycc ycc 1809750236 May 10 03:35 xxxxxx incl db.rar
ycc@x360:/media/ycc$
```

(the name of my USB flash is KINGSTON, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sudo chown -R ycc:ycc /media/ycc/KINGSTON  #reown the files
sudo chmod -R o+rwX #add ycc read and write rights. Add Execute only if the file is a directory
touch /media/ycc/KINGSTON/testfile #test if you can write on the stick.
```

Comment: Thank you. It works already after the first of the commands. (I would first have been hesitant to make the command -R. But I checked before and I stood as owner of all files in sub folders.)

Comment: @ycc_swe: No problem. Its always a good idea to check unknown flags and commands.

Comment: But if I would have stored a file with a different owner, couldn't it have caused problems making the command chown -R?

Comment: @ycc_swe: No.  The command has no problem with this. But maybe your use case for the USB stick. I assumed that you use it only to transfer data from one PC to another.